# Why i am getting 404 error on js included in html?

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

I am building a webapp using Maven, Spring 4, Angularjs and Thymeleaf. I create some Thymeleaf template ( in directoty templates/fragments ). I have attached a screenshot of my eclipse web project.[image]

The problem i am facing is about referencing libraries and css file, i am getting 404 not found on firebug.

### HTML (index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-spring4-4.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" href="/js/lib/angular.js" th:src="@{/js/lib/angular.js}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/lib/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js}"></script>
    <title>Jobly - login page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div th:include="templates/fragments/header::header"></div>
    <h1>Hello on a second page!</h1>
    <p>Click <a th:href="@{/hello}">here</a> to go back.</p>
    <div th:include="templates/fragments/footer::footer"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the snippet code of header template :

```
<link th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>

<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/lib/jquery-1.11.1.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/lib/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
```

Below the screenshot of 404 error
[image]

Comment: If you open up your developer tools (I recommend chrome but anything will do) to the network panel, what url is the request being made for?

Comment: I've just make an updated of my post

Comment: Is there any rewriting going on? Because I see your folder structure with `src/main/webapp/js/lib/...` and a 404 trying to reach `/app-web/js/lib/...`

Comment: There is no rewriting

Comment: take a look at http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/standardurlsyntax.html , your Inspector is outputting something absolutely different to your path (hence the 404), so you have something wrong, and it looks like URL rewriting, so double-check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my problem. It was a problem of specifing resources location and mapping in Spring configuration file. I add in app-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/"/>
```